# why some git commits are older than their parent?

Tags: git, github, parent, commit

I was looking at apache-drill commit [3efc2eca](https://github.com/apache/drill/commit/3efc2eca67cf53643df35a8a3c0a7663d085da57) and I realized that it is older than its parent commit [8614bae](https://github.com/apache/drill/commit/8614bae5e881dadeb556206c1e2129e9b816a50c).

I have had a couple of other similar observations.
How can I explain them?

Comment: Note that when you commit, you can set the date to whatever you want it to be. (Or date**s**, since there is one for each of the author and commit)

Comment: Thanks @Eric for the info!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commit history in git is rewritable. There are many ways that that could have happened. The most likely way is that the commit was [rebased](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) after it was created.

Answer (score 2):

You can change git history with an interactive rebase, e.g.:

```
git rebase --interactive|-i HEAD~(number of commits)
```

Here is the scenario:

```
$ git commit -m 'Commit 1'
$ git commit -m 'Commit 2'
$ git rebase -i HEAD~2
  // changing only 'Commit 1'
  edit bae2ea4 Commit 1
  pick 0e25612 Commit 2
$ git add .
$ git commit --amend
$ git rebase --continue
```

After these 'Commit 2' will be older than its parent 'Commit 1'

You should remember that you are not advised to rewrite history after your changes were published (pushed).